# Why do we need Reliable Actors reentrancy?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I can't figure out why do we need reentrancy. As I understood, calls from actor to actor isn't a good practice. And in example in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-reentrancy/) article we even have three actors calling each other.

- Is there any real example to show advantages of reentrancy and how and for what purposes it have to be used?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing where you read something that told you "calls from actor to actor isn't a good practice". That's just not the case. There are many patterns where various actors are designed to work closely together to accomplish a goal.

Comment: @DrewMarsh you can see a picture with actors using techniques at very beginning of introduction to actors [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/) and there is no actor-to-actor.
Also, if you take a look at [this](https://acom-swtest-2.azurewebsites.net/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-pattern-distributed-networks-and-graphs/) article where depicted implementation of social network on actors, you can see that if one actor will call another, then some person will become unreachable for some time.

Comment: @DrewMarsh and as it is a social network, we would expect that actors will be available and reachable with low latency as there could be a very popular user whose actor's methods will be called very often, so long delays could “paralyze” this user. Yes, I saw examples with computations and aggregation. Probably I really should not think that actor-to-actor interaction is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows an actor to process more than one request at a time when the requests are part of the same chain of actor calls. Actors are single-threaded meaning an actor can only process one request at a time. Without reentrancy, A -> B -> C -> A would deadlock. Actor to actor calls are perfectly fine as long as you play by the single-threaded rules.

Comment: I understand this, but is there any real examples of situation when you need to call the A actor from the C actor? Any examples from real life?